# Interacting with Folium Map embeded in PySide2 QWebEngineView

Tags: python, maps, pyside2, folium

This is my working directory structure

- myProj

  - folium_Map.py
  - pysideGUI.py
  - map.html

So far what i have is , i am using **folium** to create a map and save it to an html file - *map.py*. Below is the code for the *map.py*

```
folium_map = folium.Map(location=[39.3852, -100.4766],
                    zoom_start=3,
                    tiles="Stamen Terrain")

folium_map.add_child(folium.ClickForMarker())
folium_map.add_child(folium.LatLngPopup())
folium_map.save("map.html")
```

Once done with that i am rendering that *map.html* file in a PySide2 ***QWebEngineView*** . Below is the code

```
    ....
    ....
    self.webView = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView(MainWindow)
    self.webView.setGeometry(10,10,400,200)
    self.url = QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(r"path-to-map\map.html")
    self.webView.load(self.url)

    ....
    ....
```

This is the screenshot -

[image: Simple Test GUI]

Now what i want is that whenever i click on the map ,

1. **Get a Lat and Long Pop Up** -- ***Done***
2. **Get a Circular Marker on the mouse click of custom radius** - ***Currently i am getting a default marker***
3. **Communicate the coordinates to my pysideGUI.py script at each click** - ***Have no idea how to do that..!***

I would really appreciate it if anyone could help me with the 2. & 3.
Thanks

Comment: Any luck on this one yet @Dravidian ?

Comment: nope, no luck so far